# Animation cycles abruptly from last frame to first

Tags: unity, animation

I was doing some basic interactions with the animation dopesheet and noticed that image 1 to 2 takes certain time, 2 to 3 and 3 to 4 take the same amount of time, but in the loop, 4 goes almost instantly to 1. I would like to add more time before this happens. The timeline is shown below, and it's clear what is happening, but I can't figure how I extend the end part.

[image: Animation Timeline]

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a keyframe that matches 0:00  (key frame 1)) at time 0:40  (new key frame 5).

[image: repeated keyframe]

Comment: I almost have done this, but it looks a bad practice, looks like cheating. Is it bad?

Comment: Does the last frame have to match frame 1, or can it just serve as an empty placeholder to stretch the loop interval?

Comment: for sprite animation, I don't see anything bad about this practice -- why would it be "bad"? Maybe I'm missing an edge case...